# Store Values of UITableView in NSString if Scrolled Past

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an interesting requirement for an app I am working on. I have a `UITableView` with a bunch of items in it. I am trying to log which items were looked at (scrolled past). For example, if the list contains letters A-Z and the user scrolls down the `UITableView` to letter T, then values A,B,C,D,E.F....T would be stored as an `NSString` in `NSUserDefaults`.

I would like to store the actual row text as the value in the NSString. For example, A instead of 1, B instead of 2, etc...

I have done some digging around but cant seem to find anything useful. Any ideas on how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

is called every time you view a cell. You could then use a method to convert indexPath.row into an alphabetic letter and store that in NSUserDefaults

Edit - on re-reading your question I get the impression youre just talking about generic titles of the rows. Thats easy - because you have to set the title text in cellForRowAtIndexPath - so you could just pop it into defaults when you do this.

Comment: OK so lets say I am pulling all of the cell contents from a JSON feed, but I only want to store the values if they appear on the screen (i.e. the user actually scrolled to it or past it). If the UITableView contains 200+ items, and the user only scrolls past the first 25, then only the first 25 would be stored if I did this whithin the cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Just want to make sure that not all 200+ would be stored - I only want the ones the user saw

Comment: Im pretty sure only the cells the user has scrolled to will appear, so yes the first 25. Im using UICollectionView (Related to UITableView - and that works in the same way) in my project at the moment and dont have a large UITableView to double check this on. Why dont you populate the table, and put in a NSLog(@"Row seen: %i", indexPath.row) in cellForRowAtIndexPath to double check and get a feel for it.

Comment: aha simple way to do it! I will check this out soon and will let you know if it works - You rock!!!!!

Comment: I think cellForRowAtIndexPath get call for +/- 2-3 rows so far, not only the actually visible!

Comment: Ah ok. Try it with this instead (dont delete the cellForRow one): - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 1):

Make a plist ( `NSDictionary` ) and make pairs ( key- value ) like 1 - A 2- B and so on. When you want to store it, write a method, which will search your value, for a key.

if you have dynamic data:

make an `NSMutableDictionary`, and

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [dict setObject:cell.label.text forKey:indexPath.row];
```

}

EDIT:

You can get the visible rows with this method:

```
indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

Returns an array of index paths each identifying a visible row in the receiver.

```
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

Return Value
An array of NSIndexPath objects each representing a row index and section index that together identify a visible row in the table view. Returns nil if no rows are visible.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are populating the list from array containg A,B,C and etc.

Do your array would be:
(A,B,C,D,E,F,G)

So, start with converting each index of array into a NSMutableDictionary such that the array becomes as follows, here visited refers to wether that row has been visited or no, by default 0 for No:

```
(
{
value = "A"
visited = 0
},
{
value = "B"
visited = 0
},
{
value = "C"
visited = 0
},
{
value = "D"
visited = 0
},
)
```

Now on cellForRowAtIndexPath do this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *editDict = [arrayObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[editDict setInteger:1 forKey:@"visited"];
[arrayObjects replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:editDict];
```

This way all the rows that have been visited will have 1 for key "visited"

then  you can run a loop to save the values corresponding to visited = 1 wherever you want